# Можно ли говорить "это очень жаль"?

Tags: выражения, винительный-падеж

Слушаю Вертинского:

> Увы, на жизни склоне
>   Сердца всё пресыщённей,
>   И это очень жаль...

(автор стихов - В. Инбер)

Мне последняя строчка режет ухо.

Хотелось бы понять: это я ошибаюсь, или действительно фраза построена не очень удачно? Или, быть может, сто лет назад было приемлемо говорить так, а сегодня уже нет?

Comment: Мне тоже слух режет, но придраться в общем-то не к чему.

Answer (score 2):

Такое выражение встречается у многих классических литераторов (Горький, Аксаков, Гарин-Михайловский, Ключевский, Паустовский... - см. google books). Во всех случаях местоимением "*это*" ссылаются на *предшествующее* высказывание (своё или собеседника) - как и в вашем примере. Сейчас так говорят редко, но можно рассматривать данное выражение как идиоматическое сокращение более формального "мне очень жаль, что *так*". Указательное местоимение и здесь полезно, хотя оно было бы явно лишним в выражении "Это очень жаль, что...".

Comment: Даже, для наглядности, полную форму можно представить как "и очень жаль, что *это* так"

Comment: А сегодня это всё-таки звучит странно или чутьё меня подводит?

Comment: Сегодня кажется слегка просторечным (хотя встречается и в современных книгах), сам я так не говорю.

Comment: соглашусь, что фраза звучит просторечно (в противовес тому, что используется  только у старых классиков), но не неправильно. В стихе режет ухо, в обычной жизни бы не резало